# Is there any difference between UserDict and Dict?

Tags: python

If I want a class to have a dictionary behavior, why should I inherit from `dict` or `UserDict`?

Comment: What is the lowest common denominator for Python versions that you have to support?

Answer (score 8):

You can inherit from `dict` in any Python that's version 2.2 or better, but you'll have to override every single method of interest -- for example, your override of `__getitem__` will **not** be used by `get` unless you also override that one, and so on, and so forth.

The `UserDict.DictMixin` mix-in goes back a lot further and lets you implement just a few methods: the other methods, as supplied by the mix-in, **will** pick up and use your own overrides.  Note, however, from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html?highlight=userdict#UserDict.DictMixin):

> Starting with Python version 2.6, it
>   is recommended to use
>   collections.MutableMapping instead of
>   DictMixin.

The new  ABCs (Abstract Base Classes) in the `collections` module have much the same advantages as good old `UserDict.DictMixin`, wider applicability, and more regularity.